# What is the information that's always present without requiring user interaction called?

Tags: gui-design, terminology, names

I remember reading about this *type* of information displayed in a toolbar before, but I can't recall or find it on the web. Ideas?

[image]

## Update

the initial title of this question was *What is the information that's always present in a toolbar called in UX lingo?*

I always refer back to this question when I discuss designs with designers. However I believe narrowing the scope of this discussion to what appears on a *tool bar* is not helpful.. what I really meant is the kind of information that is displayed at all times, without requiring the user to do any further actions, this concept isn't specific to desktop applications (where putting status bars etc makes sense).. it also extends to the mobile world as well.. see example:

[image]

so I wonder what this *type* of visual information is called.. i don't think the term *status bar* applies here.

Comment: But this raises the question: Is naming things helpful in the UX world or not?   http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/93993/is-naming-things-helpful-in-the-ux-world-or-not

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## Status Bar

The name for the toolbar itself is the "status bar".

> **Status Bar** -
>
> a strip along the bottom of a software or Internet application that indicates what is happening with a task or information like date, time, cursor or scroll position, page number, open applications, etc.
>
> http://www.dictionary.com/browse/status-bar
>
> On a Web browser, the status bar shows the progress of loading of Web pages into the browser window. In a word processing program, the status bar would typically display information about the cursor's position within the document and often
>
> http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/status_bar.html

So that would mean that the actual data contained on the bar would be the "status". Which would make sense, it is providing the state or context of the user:

> **Status** -   state or condition with respect to circumstances
>
> http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/status

Comment: i'm not sure how using an english dictionary definition actually explains a UX behaviour/question.. but i'll trust that that's ok in the UX community considering your high rank.

Comment: @abbood Many terms that we as UX designers consider jargon or industry specific are actually well defined and accepted outside of the field. In this case the name "status bar" has been used by so many "mainstream" applications such as MS Word (they call it a status bar in their options menu) that it has been accepted as the standard. That being said I dont know everything so there may be a better name for it out there and if so hopefully someone will provide that as an answer!

Comment: In the old days, believe it or not but *all* browsers used to have these (!) and at that time it was universally known as a status bar. Internet Explorer still has the option to display one and still refers to it as a status bar.

Comment: @abbood [M$ call it Status Bar everywhere in Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760726(v=vs.85).aspx): "A status bar is a horizontal window at the bottom of a parent window in which an application can display various kinds of status information." so there is at least one IT source for quotation. (I guess we could find more info in m$ gui guidelines)

Comment: @DasBeasto revisiting this question after a while.. please see update